# Launching BlackBerry App from BlackBerry WebWorks App

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I'm still new to BlackBerry development but I am trying to find a way that if I have a WebWorks Application (Application A) and a native Application B, I would like to launch Application B with some data provided from Application A. Once Application B, it then needs to be able to pass some more data back to Application A.

I have started looking around and read through the blackberry.launch api

https://origin-bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_webrefs/blackberry_launch_971534_1...

but from there I only see that you are able to launch specific applications.

Any advice here is appreciated.
Kind Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 3):

If this is a real WebWorks applicaton, use [blackberry.invoke.invoke](https://origin-bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.invoke.html) with [JavaArguments](https://origin-bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.invoke.JavaArguments.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var args = new blackberry.invoke.JavaArguments('net_rim_bb_memo_app');
   blackberry.invoke.invoke(blackberry.invoke.APP_JAVA, args);  // Java
</script>
```

**EDIT**:
I didn't read the part about passing data back to Application A. You'll either need:

- [Write a JavaScript Extension in Java](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/documentation/creating_and_using_a_js_extensiong_in_your_widget_1316872_11.html) to return data
- Make the Application B [write to the filesystem](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/package-summary.html) and [have the webworks app read it](https://origin-bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.io.file.html).

Comment: Thanks, that worked :)
Next challenge will be getting the data back to the 1st application, so time to go try some tinkering with that JavaScript extension.