# Returning string from BlackBerry java application

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a BlackBerry WebWorks application and I need to scan QR-code.
For scanning QR-code I call a BlackBerry java application.

I want to return back a string(decoded data encrypted in scanned QR-code) from BlackBerry java application to calling application(BlackBerry WebWorks application).

How can I do that?

Can  'blackberry.invoke.JavaArguments();'  api help in this scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching BlackBerry App from BlackBerry WebWorks App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586138/launching-blackberry-app-from-blackberry-webworks-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also might consider using the community build extension already written to scan QR codes (https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/Smartphone/Barcode)